# Observers and updated class property

Tags: angular

I have class with `styles` property, which updated in template through two-way data-binding `[(ngModel)]="styles"`.

How i can create Observer based on this property, which will put to Observer subscribers new updated value each time, when i changed that property inside input?

Right now i did two thing:

1. two-way data-binding [(ngModel)]="styles"
2. input keyUp handler, in which i put class `styles` property in next() method of Subject.

Any better way to do that?

```
// template
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="styles.background" (keyup)="onInputChange($event)">


// component
private onInputChange (event): void {
    this.stylesService
        .getStyles()
        .next(this.styles);
}
```

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates what you actually try to accomplish.

Comment: It's much better but still not clear what you mean by observer. What should be observed and what should be notified about changes?

Comment: `this.stylesService.getStyles()` returns Subject. In other component i subscribe on this Subject and update 'live preview'-template styles based on subscribed value. 

I just want to know - is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Who are the subscribers?  If they're child components, you can simply use input properties on the child components, and Angular will automatically propagate changes to them.

Comment: No, not a child component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting your head wrapped around observables takes time, but it is worth it :) If I understand your question correctly, you want to build an `input` field that you can enter by hand and it's value gets emitted to all listeners that are listening to your `StylesService`, here's the code for such a service:

```js
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

@Injectable()
export class StylesService{
  public styles$: Observable<any>;  // Anyone can subscribe to this variable
  private _data: any = {};
  private _observer: Observer<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.styles$ = Observable.create(observer => {
      this._observer = observer;
    }).share();
  };

  update(newValue) {
    this._data = newValue;
    this._observer.next(newValue);
  }
}
```

You can subscribe to this service in your component like this:

```js
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent { 
  observedStyles: any = { background: 'red' };

  constructor(private stylesService: StylesService) {
    stylesService.styles$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.observedStyles = data;
    });
  }

  private onInputChange(event): void {
    this.stylesService.update({ background: event.target.value });
  }
}
```

I created a plunker so you can explore it more by yourself: http://plnkr.co/edit/MlyYKjaFPlkJPAKCik7t?p=preview